# Read data once and use later

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I read values in from a file on startup of my application.

I'd like to use those values during a condition in a timer every xx seconds later in my program's execution.

I don't want to read the file again. How do I go about referencing the values initially read in?

The timer is in a completely different project/class to initial reading of the file.

Comment: assign necessary content of the file to global variables for future use @ the time of read file occur.

Comment: Extend the timer or whatever uses the values and pass the values during initialization as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure extending the timer is a good idea as the main application doesn't know about the Timer class.  Looking like I might use the Lazy<T> as mentioned below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign them somewhere!

If you're reading from the file and creating the timer condition in the same place, you could even use a local variable to store the values.

If they need to be accessed later but you don't want to recreate them, you could store them in a field in the class where this is happening.

If these values will be used elsewhere in your application, but will remain relevant as long as this class' type is around, you could store them in a static field or property.

If you want them to be loaded on-demand and then saved for subsequent access, you could use a `Lazy<T>` type to store them.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the Lazy<T> as that sounds the best move.  I want to load them and then save them for subsequent access.

Comment: Isn't Lazy<T> more about defining an object but it doesn't 'exist' until you access it? I understand that to be the opposite of what is requested here. I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: A quick update on this answer.  I finally implemented the Lazy<T> method as mentioned by Scorpion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are needing to reference them from another class and hold them in memory - create a public static property somewhere to which you can assign the data.

```
public static MyDataType Data{ get;set;}
```

... where MyDataType is an object that holds your data. You can then test for Null in your timer method to make sure this has happened before continuing.

Comment: I'll look into this idea as well. Thanks!